# Why does Bishop keep informing Interpol, causing needless obstacles for their con?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-notice

In *Red Notice* (2021), Since Bishop and Hartley are working together, why would she keep telling Interpol where Hartley is?

Comment: True, I forgot the first time had a point. But why would she tell them that Hartley and Booth escaped prison?

Answer (score 1):

The point of the con is for Booth to take Hartley to the third egg.

This involves both Booth and Hartley having a common cause, firstly in being on the run together and, secondly, hopefully getting the other eggs away from Bishop.

So Bishop reveals that Booth & Hartley have escaped from prison to Das so that she will continue to chase them thus adding pressure on the pair.

> And the third egg, well, the only way for us to get our hands on it was if you led us right to it, which you did.
>
> I thought for sure you were gonna see through my "We're not partners,
> I gotta clear my name, I'm Johnny Law, blah, blah, blah."
>
> To be honest, I thought I laid it on too thick in the prison.